# GTM both scripts (script / no-script) in header are working?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a question for GTM tag.
Actually, the customer put GTM tags (both tags - script /no-script) in the header.
Personally, I think it works well but I am not sure because I have this messages from google tag assistant. (which can verify the tag is working well or not)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUZNw.png)

Could you give some advice for this one?
I am not sure whether this works just fine or I need to ask customer change something for this one.

Thank you

Comment: Based on experience you don't need to worry. no-script tag is almost never used anymore. Have a look at this blog for more info: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-noscript/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to implement the tag correctly you should. If you are using WordPress you could also use a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of having  and  tag is , 
 tag is used by default to collect analytics on the site and it is placed in header because its a  tag(all scripts should be in header) and to collect information immediately when the page starts loading .
The  shouldn't be placed in header section because its not a script and only scripts should be in header and also the use of  tag is if a user disables the javascript while browsing the site then the no script tag will be used to collect the analytics on the site .
So, the its always good to place script tag in header as high as possible and no script in body as high as possible